# Adding a row to a table using Jackcess in Java

Tags: java, row, jackcess

I'm trying to use Java code to add a new row to a pre-existing table in Java. The table is in an Access .mdb database file. Here is the whole of my code including the one I used to create the .mdb.

Note: I want to be able to add rows to the table with Jackcess and in a Java method.

```
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.*;
import org.apache.commons.logging.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang.*;


import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class DataManagement {
    static Database db;
    static Table Users;

    public static void createNewDataBase(){
        try{
            db = Database.create(new File("test.mdb"));
            Users = new TableBuilder("Users")
                    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("User")
                    .setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR)
                    .toColumn())
                    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Pass")
                    .setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR)
                    .toColumn())
                    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Enabled")
                    .setSQLType(Types.BOOLEAN)
                    .toColumn())
                    .toTable(db);


        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        }
    }

    public static void readDatabase(){
        try{
            System.out.println(Database.open(new File(test.mdb"))
                    .getTable("Users").display());
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public static void addUser(String name, String pass){
        try{
            Users.addRow(name, pass, true);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

    }

    // This main is present for testing purposes only
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //createNewDataBase();
        //addUser("Max", "John");
        //readDatabase();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you supplied works.  I get the output

```
User    Pass    Enabled
Max     John    true
```

In your `readDatabase` method, notice that you do not have a balanced pair of double quotes.  I used jackcess 1.2.8, commons-lang 2.6 and commons-logger 1.1 as my imported libraries and I am running with Java 1.6.

The code you wrote is very much in line with [these examples](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) and so other than compatibility or file/directory access problems, I don't see anything wrong with doing what you did.  If you still have problems, maybe try populating your exception blocks to see what is up.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question is for the older (deprecated) 1.x versions of Jackcess and  hence may be confusing to people looking for help with the current  2.x versions of Jackcess. Here is the corresponding 2.x code to create a database file, create a new table, and then add a row:

```java
package so9318569;

import java.io.File;

import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.ColumnBuilder;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DataType;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database.FileFormat;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.TableBuilder;

public class So9318569Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Database db = DatabaseBuilder.create(FileFormat.V2003, new File("test.mdb"))) {
            Table tblUsers = new TableBuilder("Users")
                    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("User", DataType.TEXT))
                    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Pass", DataType.TEXT))
                    .addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Enabled", DataType.BOOLEAN))
                    .toTable(db);
            tblUsers.addRow("Max", "John", true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }

}
```